# Call PHP code from Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am a **JS/PHP** newbie and I do not know how to unravel the following problem;

First of all, the code

**PHP** code:

```
class User {

   private $mysqli;

   function __construct($connection) {
       $this -> mysqli = $connection;
   }

   public function updateUsername($oldusername, $newusername) {
       $statement = $this -> mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE user SET username = ? WHERE username = ?');
       $statement -> bind_param('si', $oldusername, $newusername);
       $result = $statement -> execute();

       if (!$this -> mysqli -> commit()) {
           return false; // maybe beacuse an username already exists..
       } return true;
}
```

**Javascript** code:

```
var oldusername;

$(document).on("click", "span.editusername", function () {
    var txt = $(".username").text();
    oldusername = txt;
    $(".username").replaceWith("<input class='username' style=\"border: 1px solid rgb(231, 231, 231); padding: 3px 5px; color: rgb(81, 81, 81); \"/>");
    $(".username").val(txt);

    $(this).text('editing..');
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');

    $(".username").focusToEnd();
});

$(document).on("blur", "input.username", function () {
    var newuser = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith("<label class='username'></label>");
    $(".username").text(newuser);

    // Here I want to call the PHP updateUsername function with the two arguments: oldusername, newuser: booleanResult = updateUsername(oldusername, newusername);

    $('.editusername').text('edit');
    $('.editusername').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});
```

Draft of **HTML** code:

```
 <h1 id="user-displayname"><label class="username"><?php
            if($_SESSION["s_username"]) { echo $_SESSION["s_username"]; } ?></label></h1>
 <div class="sub-header-links">
    <span class="editusername">edit</span>
    <a><?php
            if($_SESSION["s_user_id"]) {
                ?>
                    <a href="logout.php" title="Logout">logout
            <?php } ?></a>
 </div>
```

Like in the following images, if I click on label 'edit', the username label becomes an editable textarea. After the change, the label is updated, and the db too, through a PHP function (updateUsername).

[image]

[image]

The logic around textarea and label is handled by the JS code, while the call to the DB should be acted by the PHP code, but I do not know how to call the PHP function from the Javascript file, and I do not even know if this is the best approach, or at least a sensible approach.

Thank you

Comment: Check out AJAX - you need to send a network request back to your server to execute that

Comment: Props to you for putting a lot of effort into the question, even if the answer is trivial :)

Comment: did you write the class ? ... smooth )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question, so thanks to all of you who had suggestions about the use of AJAX. I do not know if my solution is the best approach, but I have already tested it successfully!

As usual, first the code:

**PHP** code (db.php file):

```
$func = $_POST['func'];
if ($func) {  
    switch ($func) {
        case 'updateUsername':              
            $username = $_POST['username'];

            $isValid = $dbuser -> updateUsername($username, $_SESSION['s_user_id']);
            if ($isValid) {
                session_regenerate_id();
                $_SESSION['s_username'] = $username;
                session_write_close();
            }
            break;
        default:
            //function not found, error or something
            break;
    }
}
```

A draft of the **HTML** code:

```
$(document).on("blur", "input.username", function () {
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $(this).replaceWith("<label class='username'></label>");
    $(".username").text(txt);

    // Call to the db..
    $.ajax({
        url: "db.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { func: 'updateUsername', username: txt },
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('.editusername').text('edit');
            $('.editusername').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error!');
        }
    });
});
```

The db call into the **PHP** function:

```
  public function updateUsername($username, $userid) {
    $statement = $this -> mysqli -> prepare('UPDATE user SET username = ? WHERE user_id = ?');
    $statement -> bind_param('si', $username, $userid);
    $statement -> execute();
    if (!$this -> mysqli -> commit()) {
        return false; // maybe beacuse an username already exists..
    } return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
AJAX was made todo exactly what you are asking - allow the client to run server side code.

Also, your updateUsername method is binding a string and an integer, but looks like you are passing in two strings.

```
$statement -> bind_param('si', $oldusername, $newusername);
```

should be...

```
$statement -> bind_param('ss', $oldusername, $newusername);
```